# idiomatic phrases for *the threat to go to the police*

Tags: phrase-requests

Let's imagine a situation. One dog's master set  his pit bull on his neighbour. This dog bared teeth and did not allow the neighbour to get into his car. The dog frightened this man to death. The man threatened that he would go to the police and write a complaint [letter] about this event or that he would fill in a specific blank in the police station. What are idiomatic phrases that you would use, speaking about police? What would you say to this abuser who trains his dog in such a way?

Note, the situation is not so serious that you want call police immediately. You threaten that you'll make a complaint about this event in the police station when you'll get off work, say, tonight.

Comment: Of course, the victim was figuratively frightened to death. :)

Comment: I'm sure you can find a hundred slang words -- squeal, rat, fink on, et al.

Comment: Maybe not idioms, but I've heard it said in those situations, "Curb your dog or I'll call the cops on you!" or "I'll report you to the police next time that mutt is off of his leash!"

Comment: @Kristina Lopez Thanks, the phrase 'to report somebody to the police' is perfectly suited for the situation I described. Could you post the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the most common expressions I've heard spoken by actual people and not on a cop show are:

> ***"I'll report you to the police."***
>
> and
>
> ***"I'll call the cops on you!"***

Comment: Dropping the police entirely gives my immediate thought: “I'll report you for that!”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, but wouldn't that leave it ambiguous to whom you're threatening to report someone?  The ASPCA?  The school hall monitor?  Neighborhood Watch Captain?  I think it would be a lot more satisfying to say "I'll report you to the (bum-bum-BUM!) POLICE!" :-)

Comment: Maybe in some situations… but if someone actually sics their dog on someone else, police is pretty much the only place I would even consider. Maybe R/ASPCA, too, but that would be a distant second. I don't know why, but somehow “I'll report you to the police!” just sounds really awkward to me, like an empty, hollow threat made by someone with the air of threatening to tell on someone to their mum…

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *[drop a dime](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drop+a+dime?r=66)* is commonly used in the US

> To inform; give information, esp. to the police; dime, rat

*Dictionary.com*

I believe the origin is in the long standing amount charged for a payphone in the mid to late 20th century.

As indicated in the definition, *dime* by itself is also used.

While Dictionary.com also suggests *rat*, perhaps more common are the verbal phrases [*rat on* or *rat out*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rat)

> (informal) Inform on (someone) to a person in a position of authority:
>
> *I never thought Stash would rat on me*
>
> *men will literally choose death over ratting out another prisoner*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

All of these terms refer to the act of informing the police, not the threat of such informing. If the threat is being used to export money or action from a guilty party (I will drop a dime on you unless you do X), the terms for threat would be conventional terms, such as *blackmail* or *extortion*. An idiomatic term might be *[put the squeeze on](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/put-the-squeeze-on)*.

> informal Coerce or pressure (someone).

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I don't think I've every heard someone say "drop a dime" in my 65 years.  I've read it a few times, but (despite "dime") it sounds more British than US.

Comment: @HotLicks It may be the stuff of pulp novels and B movies more than common parlance, but its out there, and I heard it regularly growing up in the northeast US (in your same time period).

Comment: Maybe it's a northeast thing.

Comment: @HotLicks Or maybe you don't hang out with people who drop dimes on each other.

Comment: Or maybe a phone call hasn't been a time in 40 years.

Comment: Not a northeast thing, unless all the cop shows I've watched over the years all take place in the northeast.  I can't honestly say that I've heard someone I know using the phrase but it's puh-lenty idiomatically used in cop TV shows. :-)

Comment: @HotLicks Since 1984 in NY.

Comment: I haven't heard _dime_ used enough to be fully aware of its connotations; but _rat_ would surely not be applicable here. Ratting on someone implies _breaking their trust_ and telling on them to me, which would hardly be the case here unless these neighbours had some sort of sinister partner-in-actual-crime thing going on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly idiomatic, but a common phrase in this context is, "file a police report."

Answer (score 0):

We use ***[911](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/911)*** as a verb:

> **I'll *911 you!***

Some also use *[dime](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dime)* or *[5-O](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=5-O)* as a verb:

> **I'll *dime you*.**
>
> **I'll *5-O you.***

More generally:

> **I'll *visit the station*.**
>
> **I'll *stop in at the station*.**
>
> **I'll *show up at headquarters*.**
>
> **I'll *file a complaint*.**
>
> **I'll *file a report*.**

We create variants with the many [slang expressions](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/slang/some-slang-words-for-police.html) for police

> **I'll *call*:**
>
> - ***5-O***
> - ***the cops***
> - ***the fuzz***
> - ***smokey***
> - ***Dick***
> - ***The Man***
> - ***the Blue***
> - ***the Blue-boys* ...**

Comment: Perhaps you should say where you live.  For me, most of these seem very strange to nonexistent.  Only "I'll call the cops" seems not stilted.  But I'm sure the others occur elsewhere.

Comment: I have heard the three at the top of the page in Philadelphia, Pittsburgh or New York City. I have said the more general ones myself, albeit in less intimidating circumstances. The lower list is published online

Answer (score -1):

An expression for the ***threat*** itself is

***[writing on the wall](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+writing+on+the+wall)***

> from the Old Testament Story of the writing on the wall that predicted
>   the end of King Belshazzar's reign.

or connected to "Lay all the cards out on the table.":

***[layout](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/layout)***

> 1.3 A thing arranged or set out in a particular way:

Comment: "I'll have you up on charges."